# Email validation MySQL and PHP

Tags: email, verification

I want to check if email already exists in the DB, starting at this and need some help. Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connects.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$email = $_POST['email'];

$checkmail = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM utilizadores WHERE email = '$email'");

$result = $conn->query($checkmail);
if($result->num_rows == 0){
    $querygo = "INSERT INTO utilizadores (username, nome, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$nome', '$password', '$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($querygo);
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    echo 'DONT WORK';
}
```

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   C:\Sites\deca_13L4\deca_13L4_23\MiniProjeto\bussaco\registo.php on
>   line 12 Warning: Unknown: 1 result set(s) not freed. Use
>   mysql_free_result to free result sets which were requested using
>   mysql_query() in Unknown on line 0

Comment: it gives me this errors:

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\Sites\deca_13L4\deca_13L4_23\MiniProjeto\bussaco\registo.php on line 12

Warning: Unknown: 1 result set(s) not freed. Use mysql_free_result to free result sets which were requested using mysql_query() in Unknown on line 0

Comment: A http POST directly into a concatenated string that is executed against a SQL server is a recipe for SQL injection. Use prepared statements!!! Besides it will make your code easier to debug.

Comment: registo.php is the code i entered in the post. The line 12 is: $result = $conn->query($checkmail);

Comment: how you suggest i should do that? really newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, unsure what value this has in the mix of everything since that is exactly where the error occurs:

```
$result = $conn->query($checkmail);
```

So I would change your code to be like this:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connects.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$email = $_POST['email'];

$checkmail = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM utilizadores WHERE email = '$email'");

if(!$checkmail){
    $querygo = "INSERT INTO utilizadores (username, nome, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$nome', '$password', '$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($querygo);
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    echo 'DONT WORK';
}
```

But that said, it’s unclear to me where the actual needed `mysql_connect` comes from. Is that in `require_once('includes/connects.php');`? I hope so. Otherwise `mysql_query` won’t work no matter what. To execute a query you need a connection.

Comment: it solved the first problem, but still with the second error. I need to remake my email verification, something not working properly

Answer (score 0):

just make your code as simple as you can. So here:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/connects.php');


$username = $_POST['username'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$email = $_POST['email'];

$checkmail = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM utilizadores WHERE email = '$email'");

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($checkmail);
if($num_rows){
    $querygo = "INSERT INTO utilizadores (username, nome, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$nome', '$password', '$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($querygo);
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    echo 'DONT WORK';
}
```